# Control The Count of Number of Transaction Per Seconds on Single HTTP Keep-Alive Request using org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Continuation

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, apache-camel, jetty-9

How can we handle the number of count for Transaction Per Seconds of Single HTTP keep-Alive request using **org.eclipse.jetty.continuation.Continuation** Class.

I have extended the **org.apache.camel.component.http.CamelServlet** and override its service method and with Help of HTTPConsumer I get camel Exchange.

I am unable to figure out how to get number of transaction happen inside this single HttpRequest Object.

Here Is the Code:-

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
   HttpConsumer consumer = resolve(request);
if (consumer == null)
{
response.sendError(404);
return;
}
if ((consumer.getEndpoint().getHttpMethodRestrict() != null) && (!consumer.getEndpoint().getHttpMethodRestrict().equals(request.getMethod())))
{
response.sendError(405);
return;
}
if (("TRACE".equals(request.getMethod())) && (!consumer.isTraceEnabled()))
{
response.sendError(405);
return;
}
Exchange result = (Exchange)request.getAttribute("CamelExchange");
if (result == null)
{
final Continuation continuation = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(request);
//After getting continuation,
//How to get the count for Number of Transaction Happen Inside this Single HTTPRequest (in this case request object)
```

Comment: What did you do so far? Any code?

Comment: @Peter I have added the code, and put the comment as well, Suggest what need to be done to get count of Number of Transaction Happen on this Single HTTP Request object. [Consider that HTTP Request come with Keep-Alive parameter]. So In this case any number of transaction happen for this single request.

Comment: @Peter can you update on this, I am waiting for your reply

Comment: Beside that the code is purely formatted, I am missing the Camel routes with all the transaction stuff such as DB access etc.

Comment: @Peter I am not talking about DB based transaction, I know jetty support Http-Keepalive using Continuation Class. How can I get number of TPS of this single HTTPRequest